# Passing data to a Vue instance from laravel - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-blade, vue.js

I've got a laravel controller passing some data to a page, i'm trying to pass that data to the vue instance and everything I try is returning *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2*

```
new Vue({
el: '#element',

...

ready: function() {
  var raw = '{{ $cell_models }}';
  console.log(JSON.parse(raw)); 
},

...


{{ $cells_models }} // is rendered by blade
```

Why would this happen, I've tried things like

```
$cells_models->toArray()
json_encode($cells_models)
```

etc and combinations of the above and more.

Whats going on here, has anyone else seen anything similar?